# How to test component with a custom hook returning data, without infinite re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs

I am trying to setup unit tests for a component that has a custom hook that is returning some data.

This is the code for the component.

```
const Component = () => {
// This state stores the array of recipes with the changes performed by the customer.
const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
const { data: { fetchedData }, loading } = useFetchHook();

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (fetchedData) {
    setData(fetchedData);
  }
}, []);

return (
  <>
    <Row>
    {data.map((recipe) => (
      <Col data-testid={'list-item'} key={data.id}>
        <Box mb="md">
          <Card
            {...data}
          />
        </Box>
      </Col>
    ))}
  </Row>
</>
);
};

export default Component;
```

This is what I have for my hook

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import data from '../data';

const useFetchHook = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    setData(data);
    setLoading(false);
  }, 1000);

return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, [data]);

return { data, loading };
};

export default useFetchHook;
```

And this is what I have for my test, I am mocking out the hook as a module with some dummy data

```
jest.mock("../../hooks/useFetchHook", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => ({  
  loading: false, 
  data: {
    data: [
     {
      /////
     },
    ]
  } 
  }),
  }));
it('renders the list', async() => {

  act(() => {
    render(<Component/>);
    expect(screen.queryAllByTestId('list-item').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Doing this, will pass my test, but since I don't have `fetchedData` in my dependency array for that useEffect. The page will not render the data. But if I add `fetchedData` into the array. I get would get an infinite rendering loop in my test with this message

`Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.`

Anyone know what this could be?

Comment: I think the problem is not the test but the code. The `useEffect` call in `useFetchHook` has no dependency array.

Comment: sorry, the indentation is off. 

But it is [data]